# javascript image load thread and the event handler thread

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous

We want to build a google map liked javascript library to show our map data(we can not use google map or yahoo map).

We have done 60% of all the work,we can display the map tiles(img) according to user's drag operation.

Howver we found some problem:

We have a container(div element) to fill the tiles,when use drag on this container,we will do some caculatioin to see if new tiles should to be loaded.

It works. But it seems that when image are loaded,we can hardly move the mouse until imgaes are loaded completed or error.

It seems that the image load thread and the event handle thread is the same.

So any idea to fix it?

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded, although the actual *loading* of the image is probably done in another thread by the browser. Are you performing any complex computation during the dragging?

Comment: does javascript has threading i don't think so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multithreading in javascript exists, but it's still quite new.  https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers